# How to check if multiple subscriptions reached onComplete()?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have two subscriptions in an Angular 6 component.
Now I want to start a method as soon as these two subscriptions reached onComplete.

How can I do this the easiest way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin). It will emit as soon as all given Observables completed.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this now!

Comment: The URL is dead.

Answer (score 5):

You can use **forkJoin** to wait for both once both are done, then you subscribe to it as you would normally do with an observable.

Like so

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { forkJoin, Observable } from 'rxjs'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

 constructor(){
   forkJoin([this.observableTest(2000), this.observableTest(3000)])
   .subscribe(data => {
     this.runMeAfter(data)
   })
 }

  runMeAfter(data){
    alert('yeahhh done with data, check your console for data')
    console.log(data)
  }

  observableTest(delay){
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        observer.next("data to send can be object or anything");
        console.log("am done");
        observer.complete(); // to show we are done with our processing 
      }, delay);
    })
  }
}
```

The `runMeAfter` will be called as soon as both asynchronous codes are done with the processing.

Stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forkjoin-theo

Answer (score 1):

We can use merge operator which allows us to subscribe multiple observables in parallel.

```
const stream1$ = of (1,2,3);
    const stream2$ = of (4,5,6);
    const result$ = merge(stream1$, stream2$);
    result$.subscribe(
// value
      (val) => {console.log(val) },
// error
    (err) => { console.log(err) },
//on complete
    ()=>{console.log('completed') });
```

Comment: just added explanation

Answer (score 0):

forkJoin works when all the obserables have emitted one value. Similar to promise.All.

If the obserables are going to emit more than one value. You can use [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) which emits a value each time all the obserables have emitted one value.